# How to detect stats on currently running Apps (or foreground App) on latest Android?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Does the latest version of Android provide somehow developers with the option to detect which Application is currently opened in the foreground? Or maybe with a list of all opened Apps (not necesserily running in the foreground)? Assume that I can get all privileges I want from a user or switch the phone also into developer mode (but I cannot root it).

For example, I see Battery optimization Apps claiming they know how much battery each App has consumed. Which means they have the ability to track somehow something. How do they do that? Is there maybe any System information exposing runtime/usage stats for each installed App in general?

thx for your time

Answer (score 0):

> Does the latest version of Android provide somehow developers with the option to detect which Application is currently opened in the foreground?

No, for privacy and security reasons.

> Or maybe with a list of all opened Apps (not necesserily running in the foreground)?

I do not know how you wish to define "opened", but in general, this is not possible, also for privacy and security reasons.

> Is there maybe any System information exposing runtime/usage stats for each installed App in general?

[`UsageStatsManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager) addresses this area in general.

Comment: Does UsageStatsManager return stats for our own App only, or 3rd Apps on the phone too?

Comment: @Gouz: If you request the proper permission, and the user grants it manually, you have access to data across all apps.